# Dropping all tables sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Whenever I perform  `select * from tab;`  I get tables that i did not create. 
It looks like:

```
TNAME       TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
BIN$GGrKjbVGTVaus4568IEhUQ==$0 TABLE
BIN$H+a0o3uyTTKTOA8WMkNltg==$0 TABLE
BIN$IUNyfOwkS0WSEVjbn04mNw==$0 TABLE
BIN$K/3NJw5zRXyRqPixL3tqDA==$0 TABLE
BIN$KQw9SejEToywXlHp18FMZA==$0 TABLE
BIN$MOEfgWgsS0GkC/CpYW+cxA==$0 TABLE
BIN$QkUYVciPQpWBwqBhxH+Few==$0 TABLE
BIN$QmtbaOYiTHCGEE0PRiLzmg==$0 TABLE
BIN$QxF4/JShTxu8PYIx8g/L7Q==$0 TABLE
BIN$UtEI7RbiQvOYzKqJEibwKQ==$0 TABLE
BIN$VMG0FXp2ROCKbedj3Ge9hg==$0 TABLE
```

I tried performing

```
select 'drop table '||table_name||' cascade constraints;' from user_tables;
```

on spool and executing but those table were not selected. It just looks really messy and is bothering me a lot. What are they? Is there any way I can get rid of them ? Or do I have to just deal with it and work with it?

Comment: looks like they are in your trash. Not overly familiar with mysql but if it is anything like Oracle this would indicate that the tables are already dropped methinks...

Comment: I changed the tags to remove `mysql` and add `oracle`. MySQL doesn't have a tool called sqlplus, nor a system table called `tab`. And it doesn't use `||` for string concatenation by default.

Comment: @BillKarwin That makes more sense

Comment: @mrphrozenphoenix you will need to login as sysdba and "purge dba_recyclebin"

Comment: `purge recyclebin` will get rid off them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as a comment for better visibility.. 
Credits to @Tomás for pointing me in the right direction.

I had to do 
`purge recyclebin;` 
instead of `purge dba_recyclebin` since I have insufficient privilege(I am a student logged in via ssh).

If you want to turn your recycle bin off, Use `ALTER SESSION SET recyclebin = OFF;`

Answer (score 1):

**Q** What are they?

**A** Looks like tables that were dropped and preserved in the RECYCLEBIN.

---

**Q** Is there any way I can get rid of them ?

**A** You can use e.g. `PURGE TABLE BIN$GGrKjbVGTVaus4568IEhUQ==$0 ;` to remove them.

That will do them individually. Note that indexes and LOBs (and other out-of-line storage) may also have entries in the recycle bin. There are other statements you can use to clear out all entries from the recycle bin.

---

**Q** Or do I have to just deal with it and work with it?

**A** That's up to you.

There are statements to purge the recycle bin for the current user, or if you have privileges, for the entire database. You can also disable the recyclebin, or ( I think) there's an option on the `DROP TABLE` that will drop a table without keeping it in the recyclebin (so these won't be created in the future.)

There's no need for me to repeat the contents of the Oracle documentation.

Refer to: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables011.htm#ADMIN01511